# Modifying the DTO name appearing in OpenAPI (Swagger) schemas in NestJS

Tags: swagger, nestjs, schema, openapi, dto

I am facing a problem where my DTO types are named one thing, but I want them to appear with a different name in the OpenAPI doc page.
For example, I have a UserDto class that I use in my controller, but wanted it to appear as simply "User" in the schemas section (and everywhere else this applies). Is that possible? Is there any decorator I can use?
I know I can simply modify the class name, but there is already a different user class used elsewhere.
I have searched everywhere with no avail.

[image]

BTW, I am using typescript and nestjs.
Every help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of the box, Nest.js doesn't yet offer a ready-made solution. There is an open pull request (as mentioned earlier) https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/983, but when it will be merged is unknown.
You can change the DTO name in schemas using one of the following approaches:

1. Add a static name property to your DTO.

```js
  class UserDto {
    static name = 'User';  // <- here

    @ApiProperty()
    firstName: string;

    // ...
  }
```

But in strict mode, TypeScript will show an error like:
`Static property 'name' conflicts with built-in property 'Function.name' of constructor function 'UserDto'.`

2. Write a decorator with an interface as suggested in the [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/983) and use it until the desired functionality appears in Nest.js.
   The decorator adds the name property with the needed value to the wrapper class for the DTO.

```js
  type Constructor<T = object> = new(...args: any[]) => T;
  type Wrapper<T = object> = { new(): (T & any), prototype: T };
  type DecoratorOptions = { name: string };
  type ApiSchemaDecorator = <T extends Constructor>(options: DecoratorOptions) => (constructor: T) => Wrapper<T>;

  const ApiSchema: ApiSchemaDecorator = ({ name }) => {
    return (constructor) => {
      const wrapper = class extends constructor { };
      Object.defineProperty(wrapper, 'name', {
        value: name,
        writable: false,
      });
      return wrapper;
    }
  }
```

Use as suggested in the [proposal](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/983):

```js
  @ApiSchema({ name: 'User' }) // <- here
  class UserDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    firstName: string;

    // ...
  }
```

And don't forget that in TypeScript 5 the decorator API will change to something close to the implementation in JavaScript

Answer (score -3):

I solved in my case using @ApiModel

like this

```
    @ApiModel(value="MeuLindoDto")
    public class NameOriginalClassResponseDto ...
```

Comment: Could you please refer to the documentation? As far as I read, there is an open PR to solve this https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/983, an issue https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1638 and other open PR for the docs https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/1533. ApiModel is not a valid decorator.